# Can I input my own order for a ggplot path?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

[image: My plot]

In my plot above, I'm using a scatter plot as a network graph with a series of nodes. I am wanting to show multiple routes through these nodes. Is there a way I can input a list of nodes as a route so that I can connect those nodes in the order in the list with multiple routes on the same plot? geom_path() only connects them in the order the nodes are in in the dataset, can I input my own order?

```
library(ggplot2)
number <- 1:10
x <- c(10,2,38,45,34,67,23,45,25,49)
y <- c(60,50,23,35,76,37,21,75,34,56)

df <- tibble(x,y,number)

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,label=number))+
  geom_point(size=5,shape=19)+geom_text(vjust=-1)
```

Comment: welcome to SO. Could you supply code & `dput(data)` to create the plot : it will be easier to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have added standalone code which is the same problem only smaller, I'm wanting to be able to draw lines for multiple route, eg 1 to 5 to 6 to 2 etc as well as 1 to 2 to 8 to 9 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to user [Marc in the box's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71482674/7941188), but taking it a step more programmatically, you can also make use of ggplot's list nature, and create a list for each new path.

Paths as per your comment. Further comments in the code

```r
library(ggplot2)
number <- 1:10
x <- c(10, 2, 38, 45, 34, 67, 23, 45, 25, 49)
y <- c(60, 50, 23, 35, 76, 37, 21, 75, 34, 56)

df <- data.frame(x, y, number)

## list of paths
ways <- list(way1 = c(1, 5, 6, 2), way2 = c(1, 2, 8, 9))

## for a programmatic way of applying different colors - you can use any palette, really
mycols <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(ways), "Set1")
#> Warning in RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(length(ways), "Set1"): minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

## For different colors, you need to loop by index 
my_paths <- lapply(seq_along(ways), function(i) {
  ## create new data sets for each path
  data <- df[df$number[ways[[i]]], ]
  ## create a new path for each data set
  geom_path(data = data, aes(x, y), color = mycols[i])
})

## add this list to your ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = number)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 19) +
  geom_text(vjust = -1) +
  my_paths
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This works thanks! is there a way to make the edges on each route a different colour?

Comment: I've added some lines to add programmatic colouring of the paths - not sure if this is what you're after

Comment: Yeah by edges I meant the links between edge node, thats exactly what I'm after, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use factor levels to order your nodes given a certain route:

```r
library(tidyverse)

points <- tribble(
  ~id, ~x, ~y, ~type,
  1, 1, 1, "Depot",
  2, 1, 2, "Item",
  3, 2, 1, "Item",
  4, 2, 2, "Item"
)

routes <- list(
  "route1" = c(4, 2, 1), # start with 4 and then move to 1 via 2
  "route2" = c(4, 2, 3, 1),
  "route3" = c(1, 3, 1, 4)
)

route_points <- function(route, name) {
  points %>%
    mutate(new_id = id %>% factor(levels = unique(route))) %>%
    arrange(new_id) %>%
    filter(!is.na(new_id)) %>%
    mutate(route = name)
}

points %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_path(data = route_points(routes[[1]], names(routes)[[1]]), mapping = aes(color = route)) +
  geom_path(data = route_points(routes[[2]], names(routes)[[2]]), mapping = aes(color = route)) +
  geom_path(data = route_points(routes[[3]], names(routes)[[3]]), mapping = aes(color = route)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = id, color = type))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that it allows one to be added multiple times? For example, the depot point is returned to multiple times per route, is there a more elegant way to accounting for this other than inserting the depot point into the dataset multiple times? Because if I return to it in the route vector, there an error saying "Caused by error in `levels<-`: ! factor level [3] is duplicated"

Comment: Do you just have multiple routes over the same nodes (e.g. many of them traveling via the depot)? How many routes in total approx.?

Comment: Three routes per graph, each route will go through each node exactly once, except for the depot node where it may travel through 10+ times. So in total each node will be travelled through three times, once by each route.

Comment: @FOH I revised my answer

Comment: My answer does not work if any point e.g. the depot is visited multiple times

Comment: I think we need to use `igraph` and `ggraph` here instead, because factor levels must be unique

Comment: I've had a quick look at igraph and I'm not sure how I would do it, I've never used either ggraph or igraph before. I managed to plot the graph in igraph but I coudnt work out how to define locations for each node in the x and y.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `geom_path()`, and then define a new dataset with the desired order for the alternate path:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make data
set.seed(1)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(n = seq(n), x = runif(n), y = runif(n))

# re-order for alternate path
df2 <- df[sample(10),]

# plot
ggplot(data = df) + aes(x = x, y = y, label = n) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(nudge_y = 0.03) + 
  geom_path(arrow = arrow()) +
  geom_path(data = df2, arrow = arrow(), col = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I think that's the way to go - I'd generally avoid using the full data in the main call so to make subsequent calls easier